# flip coin 100 times get exactly 50 Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, coin-flipping

If I flip a coin 100 times, what is the probability that exactly 50 will be heads? My thoughts were to get the number of times exactly 50 appeared in the 100 coin flips out of 1000 times and divide that by 1000, the number of events.
I have to model this experiment in Matlab.
I understand that flipping a coin 100 times and retrieving the number of heads and adding a count to the number of exactly 50 heads is one event. But I do not know how to repeat that event 1000, or 10000 times.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
total_flips=100;
heads=0;
tails=0;
n=0;
for z=1:1000
%tosses 100 coins 
for r=1:100
    %randomizes to choose 1 or 0, 0 being heads
    coin=floor(2*rand(1));
    if (coin==0)
        heads=heads+1;
    else
        tails=tails+1;
    end
end

if heads==50
    n=n+1;
end
end
```

I have tried to encompass the for loop and the if statement within a for loop, but had no luck. How do I repeat it?

Comment: Please show us your attempt to put the for loop and if statement within another for loop. That is the right approach, let's see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: this is a math problem you can solve analytically, you dont need matlab for that...

Comment: I know, but the class requires a Matlab model to be presented as well as calculations.

Comment: The problem I am having is that n is not counting when I try to repeat the for loop and if statement within the for loop

Comment: Note that the probability can be computed theoretically as `binopdf(50, 100, .5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `tails` at all, and you need to set `heads` back to zero inside the outer `for z=1:1000` loop.

Comment: Wow thanks, missed that completely. I included the tails just for referencing to see if the first part was working. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @azumakazuma if the anser helped you solve your problem, please consider hitting the checkmark next to the answer to award credit. welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3):

although your problem is solved, here comes comments on your code:

1) You set the variable `total_flips=100`, but you do not use it in your for-loop, where it goes from 1 to 100. It could go from 1 to `total_flips`

2) Omitting for-loops: although this was not your question, but your code can be optimized. You do not need a single for-loop for your problem:

```
repititions = 1000;
total_flips = 100;
coin_flip_matrix = floor(2*rand(total_flips, repititions));  % all coin flips: one column per repitition
num_of_heads = sum(coin_flip_matrix); % number of heads for each repitition (shaped: 1 x repitions)
n = sum(num_of_heads == 50) % how often did we hit 50?
```